# patent for an interface of functions presently not in use in any mobilepp

Tags: application, provisional, mobile, app, interface

Hi i believe i have developed certain functional usage/interface in an app which are unique.

to explain - they arent invention or technological breakthrough. But would fall under the purview of user interface (UI) or utility to the users. To be more precise I am bringing 2 specific functions (which are presently accessed separately) into one screen. It gives a great utility for users for their convenience and improves user efficiency.

I have been given to understand that patent is done on the process and not the end result. And if it so, then i am pretty sure the end result that i have achieved by making the unique interface could be achieved by someone else achieving it using slightly or entirely other processes too.

My question is - can i not patent the end result here which is that specific user interface instead of the patenting of process?

Can this unique interface be patentable? or i would have to copyright it for whatever worth it is (if you can through some light if copyright can secure the novelty of interface/ functions?

Would really appreciate inputs from you all guys.

Best regards

Comment: Its possible design patents will be more appropriate than utility patents. Perhaps this link is informative: https://techcrunch.com/2015/08/03/swipe-to-patent-design-patents-in-the-age-of-user-interfaces/